# He's worked for this company for two years or He's been working for this company for two years

Tags: grammar

He's worked for this company for two years or He's been for this company for two years. I want to say I am still working in this company, does the 2 sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, they _do_ (not _does_) have the same meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the meaning is the same but keep in mind that for first sentence, time expression is incorrect. Based on what you want to induce to the mind of reader, i prefer the second sentence.